# How to use github.com/jhump/protoreflect to parse a byte array of proto message knowing the message descriptor

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I have a file containing a slice of bytes of the following protomessage.

```
syntax = "proto3";

package main;

message Address {
    string street = 1;
    string country = 2;
    string state = 3;
}
```

I have the message type described as follow:

```golang
func GetProtoDescriptor() (*descriptor.DescriptorProto, error) {

    return &descriptor.DescriptorProto{
        Name: proto.String("Address"),
        Field: []*descriptor.FieldDescriptorProto{
            &descriptor.FieldDescriptorProto{
                Name:     proto.String("street"),
                JsonName: proto.String("street"),
                Number:   proto.Int(1),
                Label:    descriptor.FieldDescriptorProto_LABEL_OPTIONAL.Enum(),
                Type:     descriptor.FieldDescriptorProto_TYPE_STRING.Enum(),
            },

            &descriptor.FieldDescriptorProto{
                Name:     proto.String("state"),
                JsonName: proto.String("state"),
                Number:   proto.Int(2),
                Label:    descriptor.FieldDescriptorProto_LABEL_OPTIONAL.Enum(),
                Type:     descriptor.FieldDescriptorProto_TYPE_STRING.Enum(),
            },

            &descriptor.FieldDescriptorProto{
                Name:     proto.String("country"),
                JsonName: proto.String("country"),
                Number:   proto.Int(2),
                Label:    descriptor.FieldDescriptorProto_LABEL_OPTIONAL.Enum(),
                Type:     descriptor.FieldDescriptorProto_TYPE_STRING.Enum(),
            },
        },
    }, nil

}
```

I would like to know how best I can use [jhump/protoreflect](https://github.com/jhump/protoreflect) to parse the content of the file using the message descriptor above.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: To clarify: Do you need to use jhump/protoreflection for a reason or could you just use [proto#Unmarshal](https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/protobuf/proto#Unmarshal)?

Comment: @mattes. Please how can I use the proto#Unmarshal with the DescriptorProto then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The typical way would be to *compile* the protocol to Go code using `protoc`:

```sh
protoc main.proto --go_out=.
```

This will generate `main.pb.go`, which will have a type called `Address`:

```golang
var addr Address
err := proto.Unmarshal(bytes, &addr)
```

If this for some reason is not do-able (e.g. you *must* do it dynamically, with a descriptor), there are options. (But it's a lot more complicated.)

1. Use a `protoc`-generated descriptor. You can have `protoc` export to a descriptor file (via the `-o` flag). If this is for RPC, have the server use [server reflection](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/server-reflection.md#known-implementations); you can then use the [github.com/jhump/protoreflect/grpcreflect](https://godoc.org/github.com/jhump/protoreflect/grpcreflect#Client) package to download the server's descriptor (presumably generated by `protoc`).
2. If you *must* create the descriptor programmatically, instead of using `protoc`, I recommend using the [github.com/jhump/protoreflect/desc/builder](https://godoc.org/github.com/jhump/protoreflect/desc/builder) package to construct it (instead of trying to create raw protos by hand). For example, your raw protos are not sufficient since they have no parent `FileDescriptorProto`, which is the root of any descriptor hierarchy. That builder package can take care of details like that for you (e.g. it will synthesize a parent file descriptor if necessary).

In any event, the descriptor you want is a `desc.Descriptor` (from the [github.com/jhump/protoreflect/desc](https://godoc.org/github.com/jhump/protoreflect/desc) package). The tips above (using other protoreflect sub-packages) will return `desc.Descriptor` instances. If you only have the raw descriptor protos (like in your example code), you'd want to first turn your `*descriptor.FileDescriptorProto` into a `*desc.FileDescriptor` using the [desc#CreateFileDescriptor](https://godoc.org/github.com/jhump/protoreflect/desc#CreateFileDescriptor) function.

If you are using `protoc` and its `-o` option to create a descriptor set file (don't forget `--include_imports` flag, too), you can load it and turn it into a `*desc.FileDescriptor` using the [desc#CreateFileDescriptorFromSet](https://godoc.org/github.com/jhump/protoreflect/desc#CreateFileDescriptorFromSet) function. Here's an example:

```
bytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile("protoset-from-protoc")
if err != nil {
  panic(err)
}
var fileSet descriptor.FileDescriptorSet
if err := proto.Unmarshal(bytes, &fileSet); err != nil {
  panic(err)
}
fd, err := desc.CreateFileDescriptorFromSet(&fileSet)
if err != nil {
  panic(err)
}
// Now you have a *desc.FileDescriptor in `fd`
```

Once you have that right kind of descriptor, you can create a [*dynamic.Message](https://godoc.org/github.com/jhump/protoreflect/dynamic#NewMessage). You can then unmarshal into that using either the `proto#Unmarshal` function or using the dynamic message's `Unmarshal` method.

Comment: Thank you so much for the details explanation.

Comment: It did work but the challenge I am having is when the descriptor File set is in json format

Comment: @josh is there a wiki or document with examples I can read to get on how to use the descriptor files? Appreciate it if you could point me to it. Thanks.